# How to fix this issue with python behave not being recognized

Tags: python, python-behave

So I followed the tutorial on python behave and how to install it. I did everything that it said and `behave` command can never be found even after adding environment variables.

I used this https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I constantly keep getting command is not recognized.

I have also looked at a lot of other stack overflow questions but neither of them are actually helpful nor have any good answers.

Comment: On windows, depending on the how and what installer was used, sometimes `Scripts` folder is not added to `PATH`. Open command prompt and run `echo %PATH%` and see if you have `C:\Python310\Scripts` in the list .. if not, add it and that should fix the issue..

Comment: I have used pip install behave and then updated it just in case. I have also added the scripts into my environment variables and that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: paste the output of following commands: `where behave` and `echo %PATH%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error for hours, I have finally figured out what was missing from Environment Variables.

If you're running into the same issue of `behave` not being found try going into your roaming folder by using `run` and typing `%appdata%` this will take you to your roaming folder. Inside there find `Python\Python310\Scripts` add the whole path into your system environment variables and that should fix the issue.

Also during the installation process if you're using pip use this command `pip install behave --user`
Explanation of what is  [--user](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+--user+mean+during+pip+install&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB991GB991&sxsrf=ALiCzsYP48PsGPDVwNEDsdscWjqN5tI3Ew%3A1657788057763&ei=mdbPYquZLomI8gLgo7iwDA&ved=0ahUKEwjrya7i_ff4AhUJhFwKHeARDsYQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=what+does+--user+mean+during+pip+install&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOgoIABCxAxCDARBDOg4ILhCABBCxAxCDARDUAjoECAAQQzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6DQgAEIAEEIcCELEDEBQ6CAgAELEDEIMBOgUIABCABEoECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWKdYYK1ZaA1wAXgAgAGrAYgB0RqSAQQ0Ny40mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz#:%7E:text=The%20%2D%2Duser%20flag,system%20Python%20installation.)